# Index error in my code controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When I run my project index, it shows this error. I have googled it but I have not found a proper solution for this error. So, please someone help me.

The Error message:

> "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter
>   'chapterIdS' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(Int32)' in
>   'opr.Controllers.QuizeController'. An optional parameter must be a
>   reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional
>   parameter.
>       Parameter name: parameters"

This is my Index code:

```
@model List<opr.Data.Chapter>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h4>Select Chapter</h4>
<div class="container">
    <div class="alert-info form-control m-auto w-75 custom-form col-6">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Quize", FormMethod.Get))
    {
            <h4>Quizes</h4>
            <hr />
            foreach (var std in Model)
            {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        @Html.RadioButton("searchBy",@std.Chapter_Name, true)
                        <text>@std.Chapter_Name</text>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4"></div>
                </div>
                 <hr />        
                <h3>Questions</h3>
                <hr />
                <table>

                    <tbody>
                        @foreach (var quesion in std.C_QuestionTable)
                    {

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <h5>@quesion.QuestionText</h5>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    foreach (var answer in quesion.C_AnswerTable)
                      {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@answer.Options</td>
                    </tr>
                        }

                        }
                    </tbody>

                </table>



                }
                <input type="submit" value="Create Question" />
                }
            </div>
        </div>

this my controller
public class QuizeController : Controller
    {
        examsEntities db = new examsEntities();
        public ActionResult Index(int chapterIdS)
        {
            List<C_QuestionTable> ques = new List<C_QuestionTable>();
            ViewBag.ques = db.C_QuestionTable.Where(w => w.Id == chapterIdS).ToList();

            List<Chapter> model = new List<Chapter>();
            model = db.Chapters.Where(w=>w.Id==chapterIdS).ToList();
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Index(int chapterIdS)`...this means that there MUST be a `?chapterIdS=` in your query string, and the value after the equals sign must be an integer value. If the parameter is optional, you can make it an `int? chapterIdS`, and then check to see if it has a value and handle it accordingly if not.

Answer (score 0):

Default route expects optional parameter named `id`:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id)
{
  ...
}
```

Therefore, if your url looks like `.../Quize/Index/1` you need to call this parameter `id`, or register your own route for this controller.

Comment: Yes, that is the line that causes the problem, but you don't give any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this...

```
 public ActionResult Index(int? chapterIdS)
    {
        List<C_QuestionTable> ques = new List<C_QuestionTable>();
        ViewBag.ques = db.C_QuestionTable.Where(w => w.Id == chapterIdS).ToList();

        List<Chapter> model = new List<Chapter>();
        model = db.Chapters.Where(w=>w.Id==chapterIdS).ToList();
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now parameter will accept the null value.